# PHP MySQL: Update a Join table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relationship

I'm a bit confused as to how to best update a join table.

```
Presentaion
id PK

Asset
id PK

PresentationAsset
presentationid
assetid
```

So when updating a Presentation and it's associated assets within PresentationAsset, do I first search for all relationships, delete those and then create new ones?

What's the best approach to a scenario like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly *easiest*, at least, to delete them all and create new ones. After all, it's only two queries.

```
DELETE FROM PresentationAsset WHERE presentationid = 1
INSERT INTO PresentationAsset VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)
```

Assuming those are indeed the only two columns in that table (no timestamps or anything, for example), I can't imagine any reason you'd need to complicate it any more than that.

After all, the alternative to wiping your existing rows and inserting all new ones would be to keep the ones that already exist, but delete ones that no longer should, and insert new ones. Essentially, you're still ending up with at least one `DELETE` and one `INSERT`, so there shouldn't be much performance difference in most real world applications. Performance may even be better in the first approach, since it requires less value checking per operation.

Of course, if you're working with a large enough scenario where such a minute performance difference would be important, you'd probably want to do real tests of all your options and measure performance yourself.

And of course, if those *aren't* the only two columns in your table, you'll need to properly keep the values of the other columns for the rows you're updating, so deleting all and inserting new wouldn't be an option anyway.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I was thinking. It would be too much of a pain to search for existing data, match up the ones that aren't changing and so forth. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1) Delete all the assets and create the new ones as you said (def easier to code and easier to debug. If you don't have a PK in PresentationAsset, the only issue you may have is that several deletions could leave lots of data on the PresentationAsset PK.)

2) Do this (in pseudocode)

- Get all the ids from the assets currently associated with the presentation (old values). I will refer to this as array1
- For each asset in the new values:

  - if it is already there, update it with its new values and remove its id from array1
  - if it's not, create it
- Delete all the PresentationAsset whose PresentationId = currentPresentationId AND AssetId IN array1

Hope it is clear enough, and hope I understood your problem correctly ;) I think I can live with 1), but 2) is probably better. You update the values that need updating and delete those that were removed.